# Moving an SKNode to multiple positions; stopping at each one

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, sknode

I am making a game (an Advance Wars clone to be precise), and I am trying to make the Unit's move.

Here is the code I am using at the moment.

```
- (void)constructPathAndStartAnimationFromStep:(SKNode *)tile {
    [movementPath removeAllObjects];
    do {
        if (tile.parentTile != nil) {
            [movementPath insertObject:tile atIndex:0];
        }
        tile = tile.parentTile;
    } while (tile != nil);
    [self popStepAndAnimate];
}

- (void)popStepAndAnimate {
    if ([movementPath count] == 0) {
        selectedNode.isMoving = NO;
        [self unMarkPossibleMovement];
        return;
    }
    SKNode *s = [movementPath objectAtIndex:0];
    SKAction *moveAction = [SKAction moveTo:s.position duration:0.4];
    SKAction *moveCallback = [SKAction performSelector:@selector(popStepAndAnimate) onTarget:self];
    [movementPath removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [selectedNode runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[moveAction, moveCallback]]];
}
```

The problem is that the Unit's don't even move. Or if they do, only about half the distance they should. They also don't complete the action of movement before the next one even gets called.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I suggest using a sequence. For example to make projectiles I use this... SKAction* bulletAction = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction moveTo:destination duration:duration],
                                                  [SKAction waitForDuration:3.0/60.0],
                                                  [SKAction removeFromParent]]];

Comment: I take it your duration is 3.0?

Comment: Not exactly, after [SKAction moveTo:destination duration:duration] completes, it waits 3.0/60.0 of a second before executing [SKAction removeFromParent].

Comment: Ah, ok. that isn't quite what I am wanting. What I am wanting, is to say move the Unit one tile, then once it has finished moving to that tile, move to the next one and so forth. Any ideas on that?